# KDE Plasma desktop grid effect is too dark to see

Tags: kde, plasma

I'm currently using KDE Plasma's desktop grid effect.
It works well when I move the mouse pointer to a corner of the screen.
But the problem is that all items become darker by default making it hard to distinguish one from another.
Is there any method to *not* darken the contents so much?

Comment: Your issue reminds me of https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385522 where users want "Present Windows" not to look dark. I suggest you file a separate bug for the desktop grid effect.